# Play RTMP stream on Android with gstreamer

Tags: android, gstreamer

I'm new in gstreamer. I'm trying to create a pipeline which will be able to play rtmp stream. I googled this a lot, and as I understood, I must recode video  to other format. This is my pipeline:

```
data->pipeline = gst_parse_launch("rtmpsrc location=\"rtmp://193.93.236.33:443/rtmp&file=Lenina347 live=1\" ! glimagesink name=sink sync=false", &error);
```

I also understand that I should add some plugins between `rtmpsrc` and `glimagesink`. My question is: **What shoud I add?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution of my problem. 
Now,  I'm using playbin to play rtmp stream. Playbin support playing rtmp out of the box, but it's important to pass to `location` property right link, i.e.:

`rtmp://hostname[:port]/path/rtmpfile`.

**Important ** there must be two slashes after hostname. Also I noticed port is optional.